# Returning the time (in seconds) between the 2 times I open the program

Tags: python, csv, time, backup

I want to recieve the time in seconds between the two runs where I type `y` in the python shell.

I am sorry earlier I did not specify what I want it to be.
Basically this is the program I am testing to implement in another big program (bigger than this one).

Here is what I want the output to be:

First I will run the program and it will ask if I want to borrow and I will click `y`.
After that I will run the program again and it will ask me to return, again I will click `y` and it should return the time in seconds for which I borrowed. the cycle will continue.

This is the program which I need for a library management system.

```
import time
import csv
data_backup1=[]
f=open("a1.csv",'r')
csvr=csv.reader(f)
for line in csvr:
    #copying data into a temporary storage area from csv file
    print(line)
    data_backup1.append(line)
print(csvr,"this is csvr")    
f.close()
l=[]
if len(data_backup1)==0:
    f=open("a1.csv",'w')
    csvw=csv.writer(f)
    a=input("Enter y to borrow")
    if a=="y":
        m="borrowing"
        l.append(m)
        print(l)
        print("this is l")
        n=time.time()
        l.append(n)
        print(l)
        print("this is l")
        csvw.writerow(l)
        f.close()
    f.close()    
    f=open("a1.csv",'r')
    csvr=csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvr:
        print(line)        
else:
    a=input("Enter y to return")
    if a=="y":
        c=[]
        f=open("a1.csv",'r')
        csvr=csv.reader(f)
        c=csvr[1]
        print(c,"this is c")    
        b=c[1]
        print(b,"this is b")
        b=int(b)
        print(time.time()-b)
        f.close()
        f=open("a1.csv",'w')
        f.close()
```

I would like to get some suggestions.

Here is what I actually got in between the two runs.
Please note that I have already created `a1.csv`.

run 1

```
<_csv.reader object at 0x00000231EA788640> this is csvr
Enter y to borrowy
['borrowing']
this is l
['borrowing', 1597526322.2194974]
this is l
['borrowing', '1597526322.2194974']
[]
```

In run 1 I don't know why another `[]` is being added so please also help in that area.

run 2  - here I want it to return the time but am getting an error:

```
['borrowing', '1597526322.2194974']
[]
<_csv.reader object at 0x0000018A1B2E8640> this is csvr
Enter y to returny
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CCFFIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\test.py", line 39, in <module>
    c=csvr[1]
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable
```

I used `print` in some places to identify the error which are not at all necessary.

Also, if possible, please suggest other methods of measuring the time difference (in seconds) between two successive data entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below. For issue 1: you need to add - newline='' while opening the file for write. And for 2nd issue: reader object needs to be converted to list before it can be used with subscripts.

```
import csv
import os
import time
data_backup1=[]
l=[]
file_exists = os.path.exists('a1.csv')
if file_exists:
    f=open("a1.csv",'r')
    csvr=csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvr:
        #copying data into a temporary storage area from csv file
        print(line)
        data_backup1.append(line)
    print(csvr,"this is csvr")
    f.close()

if len(data_backup1)==0:
    f=open("a1.csv",'w',newline='')
    csvw=csv.writer(f)
    a=input("Enter y to borrow")
    if a=="y":
        m="borrowing"
        l.append(m)
        print(l)
        print("this is l")
        n=round(time.time())
        l.append(n)
        print(l)
        print("this is l")
        csvw.writerow(l)
        f.close()
    f.close()
    f=open("a1.csv",'r')
    csvr=csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvr:
        print(line)
else:
    a=input("Enter y to return")
    if a=="y":
        c=[]
        f=open("a1.csv",'r')
        csvr=csv.reader(f)
        line=list(csvr)
        c=line[0]
        print(c,"this is c")
        b=c[1]
        print(b,"this is b")
        b=int(b)
        print(round(time.time())-b)
        f.close()
        f=open("a1.csv",'w')
        f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you but can you try to give me the program without using "try"... Actually I don't understand how to use try. and #f=open("a1.csv",'w') #f.close() I kept that to delete the record in the file if you have any other method to do that please give that to me as well. and also what does newline do..

Comment: I have added back empty file write at the end and I have removed try block. But, in the end you will have to learn try-except to make sure you handle all runtime errors, for example: in your 1st step, you are assuming that file a1.csv will be always available to read, what if it isn't. There are alternate ways to handle those errors, like I have done here using ```os.path.exists```. But then, you will have to know all errors upfront.  For newline, please check footnote in this [article](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3).